# How can I get rid of the error "'folder_name' not valid as filename in directory" in TortoiseSVN 1.8.1 when checking out?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When trying to check out a repository, I get:
[image]

My TortoiseSVN version is:
[image]

I downgraded to TortoiseSVN 1.7.13:
[image]

With TortoiseSVN 1.7.13, the check out works fine but I cannot update/commit and it says I need to "upgrade working directory".

[image]

[image]

When trying to "upgrade working directory", it complains about a "missing default entry":

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: What version of Subversion do you have on the server?

Comment: Subversion version 1.6.12 (r955767) (as printed in the HTML listing).

Comment: Your 1.8 working copy is inaccessible to your 1.7 client - it's a one-way upgrade/conversion. IOW, your working copy isn't usable until you upgrade back to 1.8.x.

Answer (score 10):

Remove the space in the folder's name. In order to rename folder, open Repository Browser and rename the folder.

Subversion can handle spaces in the file/folder name, but windows can not. The problem is appearing during checkout or export, as windows does not allow the creation of a folder with a name ending with a space.

Comment: Subversion handles spaces in filenames perfectly fine. Unless you can explain *why* this will solve the problem (and how to remove the spaces if the OP can't update working copy so he can commit), this isn't even close to an answer.

Comment: In order to rename folder, open Repository Browser and rename the folder.
I had exacty the same issue. Renaming fixed the issue. I see no reason why you voted down.

And "yes", subversion can hanle spaces in the file/folder name, but not at the end. The problem is appearing during checkout or export, as windows does not allow to create a folder with the name, which ends with space.

Comment: This is the correct answer, absolutely! I was having the same issue, and after reading this post, I realized that the problematic folder also had a space at the end. Removing the space fixed the problem! I do not understand why this answer got so many downvotes!

Comment: @AraSargsyan I'm not allowed to rename the folder (I do have a SVN access but this folder is managed by somebody else I don't want to change anything: I just need to retrieve a local copy).

Comment: Not only trailing spaces can cause problems, but also trailing periods, for example a directory named 1.0.1. would fail to checkout on windows

Comment: `Subversion can handle spaces in the file/folder name, but windows can not.` This is wrong. Windows can handle spaces in file/folder names just fine. In fact, by default there (not just one) such folder on every Windows: _Program Files_
`windows does not allow the creation of a folder with a name ending with a space` Yes it does. Windows Explorer may not, but Windows itself does so.