# Skipping files with invalid filenames during checkout with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there any way to skip [files with invalid filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18452218/395857) during checkout with TortoiseSVN (Windows 7)?

By default, if TortoiseSVN runs across a file with invalid file name, it aborts the checkout:

[image]

I'd like TortoiseSVN to ignore such files and continue the checkout.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is to perform a [sparse checkout](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html)  (also see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html). Then manually update the files that you *do* want.

Or, rename your files to be compatible with all filesystems your project might be checked out to.

Comment: Thanks. Sparse checkout would be extremely tedious given the amount of folders in this SVN repo :/ I can't rename files either as I'm not supposed to commit anything yet there. (also, to be able to rename the file, don't I have to check out first? Unless this can be done in the repo browser?)